# Draw on a large canvas, scroll it, save it, reload it ... works, but only the viewport part is saved

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

My program can draw 2D shapes on a canvas. The result can be scrolled. , When I save the result, then ONLY the image in the viewport is saved.

I use a View and draw on it's canvas.

Saving the drawing/updated result is:

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( this.getDrawingCache());   
setDrawingCacheEnabled( false);    
// the bitmap I can save into a file
bm.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, new FileOutputStream( new File( filepath)));
```

When I use a large view/canvas, then I get errors that my drawingCache is not big enough. When I use a regualar view/canvas size, then nearly all drawings outside the viewport are clipped.

==> Can I draw on a bitmap and have that bitmap immediately drawn on the view's canvas?

So, after some drawing, the initial bitmap is updated with the newly added drawing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happily, there is a simple solution to this question.

1. Create a large bitmap with your own size;
2. Create your own cachedCanvas = new Canvas( largeBitmap);
3. Draw first on the cachedCanvas'.
4. In onDraw() do: canvas.drawBitmap( cachedBitmap, 0, 0, null);

Saving your own largeBitmap is easy!